# Method returning corrupt values

Tags: c++

I seem to be getting corrupt values when returning. The image illustrates the output of a loop.

[image]

```
// loop
float *bo = getBoundaries(); // this calls the method displayed below
cout << "\ngetDisplay: " << bo[0];
// loop

float* getBoundaries()
{
    cout << "\ngetB: " << x1; // this displays the correct value
    float boundaries[4] = {};
    boundaries[0] = x1;
    boundaries[1] = x2;
    boundaries[2] = y1;
    boundaries[3] = y2;
    cout << "\nfinal: " << boundaries[0]; // this also displays the correct value
    return boundaries;
}
```

This happened when I was changing from debug to release mode, however it has now affected both debug and release.

Comment: Compile your programs will all warnings enabled, you should get a warning about returning a reference to a temporary.

Comment: Use `std::vector<float>` instead of `float*`, and your problem will go away.

Comment: Or, for a small fixed-size array, `std::array<float, 4>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return boundaries;
```

Using a pointer to a function local that goes out of scope is undefined behavior.  When `getBoundaries()` returns, the `boundaries` local goes out of scope and therefore dereferencing the returned pointer could do anything, including crashing the program.

Since arrays cannot be returned by value but structs can, one option would be to return a struct containing an array:

```
struct boundaries {
    float v[4];
};

boundaries getBoundaries() {
    boundaries b;

    b.v[0] = x1;
    b.v[1] = x2;
    b.v[2] = y1;
    b.v[3] = y2;

    return b;
}

// Then in your loop:
boundaries bo = getBoundaries();
cout << "\ngetDisplay: " << bo.v[0];
```

You could also return `std::vector<float>`, or (if you have C++11) then the best option would be `std::array<float, 4>`.

Comment: Hmm how would this explain it working before I changed anything?

Comment: @KarlMorrison Nothing in this answer precludes the possibility that it would work as you intended. "Undefined behavior" means that anything can happen, *including* the program working as you intended. What likely happened is that the code-gen before didn't touch the space allocated on the stack for `boundaries` but when you changed something, that stack space is getting re-used inside of the function containing the loop, so the data there is being clobbered before you have a chance to read it. If UB does what you intend then a seemingly innocuous change can suddenly make it break. UB is bad.

Comment: The array<float, 4> has fixed everything! I will use it from now on.